# combine string array with the same string in matlab

Tags: matlab

Another is it possible question.

given a string array

```
M = [a      b
    011     10
    001     10
    112      4
    015      2
    086      1
    117      1
    121      2]
```

as you can see those values are string not numbers, 
 so i want to combine rows with the same strings, for example 011 and 001 have the same b which is 10, so this what the output i want:

```
 T = [a        b
    011,001    10,10
    112        4
    015,121    2,2
    086,117    1,1]
```

so as you can see again , 011, and 001 combine they have the in the same cell as well as 086 and 117, i want an output that when you copy and paste to word 011 and 001 or all combine string must be shown, and what if you n x 2 string array
meaning you don't know the rows size of your array.
so is it possible? thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why 015 and 121 are not grouped in the output, as their value in the second column is 2 ?

Comment: i'm sorry they should included, i will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be to convert your string into cells. Here is a solution:

```
% --- Define M
M = [sprintf('%s\t%s\n', 'a', 'b') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '011', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '001', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '112', '4') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '015', '2') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '086', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '117', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '121', '2')]

% --- Convert into cells
tmp = textscan(M, '%s\t%s\n');
C1 = tmp{1};            % First column
C2 = tmp{2};            % Second column

% --- Group

% Get unique values of the second column
UV = unique(C2, 'stable');

% Prepare result columns
R1 = {};
R2 = {};

% Group
for i = 1:numel(UV)

    b = ismember(C2, UV{i});
    R1{i,1} = strjoin(C1(b), ',');
    R2{i,1} = strjoin(C2(b), ',');

end

% --- Convert the result to a string
Res = '';
for i = 1:numel(R1)
    Res = [Res sprintf('%s\t%s\n', R1{i}, R2{i})];
end
```

The `Res` string then contains:

```
Res =

086,117 1,1
011,001 10,10
015,121 2,2
112 4
a   b
```

Which is not exactly the output you desired, since it is not sorted. If you want the output to be sorted, please precise on what criteria.

---

**Edit**

I corrected the code such that the output appears in the order defined by the second column of the input. The `'stable'` parameter of `unique` did the trick.

The output is now:

```
Res =

a        b
011,001  10,10
112      4
015,121  2,2
086,117  1,1
```

Comment: Please define what the right order is. Is it alphabetical or the initial order of appearance ?

Comment: is it also applicable for n x 2 array i mean is a general code? thanks.

Comment: A n-by-2 array string array is possible in Matlab, but it is not what you are using. Can you precise what is the class of the input ? What is the output of `class(M)` ?

Comment: i mean the order in my output please check my problem

Comment: the edited code gives an error: Error using strjoin (line 52)
First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.

Error in res (line 29)
    R1{i,1} = strjoin(C1(b), ',');

Comment: What is your version of Matlab ? `strjoin` has been modified a few times in the last releases

Comment: First, can you please specify the type of your input M? Please post the output of `class(M)`.